# problem during install gallery2 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, gallery, drupal-modules

I have some problems during install module gallery2 for my local site with drupal.

The warning in step 2 (follow this picture): http://i108.photobucket.com/albums/n33/ligthing_illuminate/1-2.png

make the install doesn't complete in step 8.

So, anyone can help me?

How to make the translation support to be successful?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps activate locale in the module list

or you could install i18n (translation module drupal) and activate that... maybe that'll help.